# Given this from InputRoot in ESQL (Split Esql)

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

```
<xml>*** 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7**<xml>
```

I'd like to create this in my OutputRoot:

```
<xml> <a>1</a> <b>2</b> <c>3</c> <d>4</d> <e>5</e> <f>6</f> <g>7</g> </xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to this,

Tactical Solution: use ESQL TRANSLATE() to replace the required characters
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05261_.htm

Strategic Solution: If this is a regular requirement create message models using DFDL then you can just switch or map between the two formats as required.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bd40450_.htm